# Backtick formatting in numbered bullets is missing the background in the mobile app

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, ios-app

In the iPhone mobile app, code formatted with backticks in bullet points has no background whereas the the same text has a grey background elsewhere.

In [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869384/reload-a-div-and-move-previous-content) the new text in the numbered bullets there is no grey background on the mono-spaced font.

Here is a screenshot in the app:

[image: iPhone app rendering]

Here is a screenshot in Chrome for iPhone:

[image: mobile web version]

I tested with a smaller sample:

[image: backticked text in a bullet and outside]

Comment: So to clarify: the text formatted with backticks in the numbered bullets at the bottom doesn't have a grey background colour like the other back-ticked text?

Comment: Yup. The stuff after "edit 2" was added like an hour a ago, and the rest is a month old.

Comment: I think it is much more relevant that the text is part of the numbered bullets :-)

Comment: Oh! Is that what is supposed to happen after bullets? Lemme check if its the bullets.

Comment: Your right! That is what it is!

Comment: @Jongware: in the bulleted list there is **no** background colour. That's the bug, the rendering is different.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this be corrected? Who is responsible for this?

Comment: The developers at Stack Exchange would. They monitor all Meta sites for bugs in their respective areas.

Comment: -1, No freehand red circles.

Comment: lol @Zanon... read the description dude

Comment: @kumar_harsh, I didn't downvote. It's a [meta meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to). I've suggested this because a fast reader (like me) have to read 2 times to understand. The first Martijn comment implies that he had doubts too.

Comment: aah, thanks for the link :)
Anyways, I knew you didn't downvote by clicking on the score :P

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in 1.3.2.  [A full explanation of my screw up is on MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254204/235711)